# PHP: How to add russian ruble using number_format

Tags: php

I am developing a shopping cart and displaying russian rubles using this number format:

```
number_format($price, 0, ',', ' ');//Example 15 525 instead of 15525
```

Now, when I add the subtotal with the shipping cost
For example:

**Subtotal** :61 305 
**Shipping**:  8 250
I get following result
69 instead of 69 555
How can I add them correctly using the number format above?

Comment: Isn't it an option to convert them back to using a dot, and then reformat it again?

Comment: better do the calculation before so that you dont have trouble like this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're modifying the price values to change their display *before* you try to add them together. If your code looks like this:

```
$subtotal = number_format($price, 0, ',', ' ');         // 61 305
$shipping = number_format($shipping_cost, 0, ',', ' '); // 8 250

$total = $subtotal + $shipping;            // $total = "61 305" + "8 250" = 61 + 8 = 69
```

then PHP is going to convert the **formatted numbers** to decimals, which means stripping off everything after the whitespace.

The best solution for this would be to change your $total variable so it adds the variables *before* formatting, not after.

Answer (score -1):

You should add the values together beforehand like so:

```
$subtotal = 61305;
$shipping = 8250;
$total = $subtotal + $shipping;
```

Use money_format() to correctly format it

```
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'ru_RU');
echo money_format('%i', $total) . "\n";
```

Output is:

```
69 555,00 RUB
```